# Error with adding Realm to iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, realm

I adding Realm for swift as Dynamic framework and I use Swift head (`#import "ProductName-Swift.h"`). On compile, I get next error:

```
Viewer-Swift.h:145:31: Declaration of 'RLMNotificationToken' must be imported from module 'Realm.RLMRealm' before it is required.
```

How I can fix it? I use XCode 7.2.

Comment: try this link https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2512

Comment: I don't understand, how to do it.

Comment: @OkadzakiTomoe It looks like you're going to use to mix Swift and Objective-C, right? Then which did you add framework, Realm or RealmSwift?

Comment: So which did you add framework, Realm.framwork or RealmSwift.framework? Or both?

Comment: @OkadzakiTomoe Can you show your code around compile errors?

Comment: @kishikawa-katsumi, thx you for true direction. In pure.m file, all are working.

Comment: Please post a response.

Answer (score 4):

Can work around this changing declaration scope of the NotificationToken variable to private like this:

```
    //var token: NotificationToken? = nil
    private var token: NotificationToken? = nil
```